# Access this in a field initializer in flutter widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

this is my first flatter app. What I try to do is ab container layout like this:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;

  Position _currentPosition;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                        title: Text("LocInfo"),
                ),
                body:
        ListView(
          children: [
            //_getCurrentLocation(),
            locSection,
            addressSection,
            timeSection,
          ],
        ),
        );
    }
```

Inside the layout I have this widget:

```
Widget locSection = Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        /*1*/
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            /*2*/
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
              child: Text(
                'Location (LAT/LNG)',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (_currentPosition != null)
            Text(
              "LAT: ${_currentPosition.latitude}, LNG: ${_currentPosition.longitude}",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey[500],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      /*3*/
      Icon(
        Icons.near_me,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

I have also a function to get the coordinates:

```
_getCurrentLocation() {
    final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;

    geolocator
            .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
            .then((Position position) {
                setState(() {
                    _currentPosition = position;
                });
      _getAddressFromLatLng();
            }).catchError((e) {
                print(e);
            });
}
```

The problem is, that I get this error:

> lib/home_page.dart:52:21: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field
>   initializer to read '_currentPosition'.
>                   if (_currentPosition != null)

So how can I access `_currentPosition` in this position?

Answer (score 0):

So, your

```
Widget locSection = Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),...
```

is like initializer and at this point, the instance of _HomePageState is not yet formed. So you cannot access its variables _currentPosition.

You can either create locSection during the initializer of _HomePageState (in constructor) or after its initialisation (in initState for example) and then it will work fine.

Comment: So you mean in this part: `class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}`

Comment: I am really confused. Here is my full code: https://gist.github.com/MalteKiefer/556b2181f6e30ad536468c005ef55104

Comment: I mean like this: 
Widget locSection; //Variable
  _HomePageState() { //This is constructor)
    locSection = Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
    //You can access _currentPosition here
    ...
  }

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. So you mean here: class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

Comment: in short, create locSection inside the constructor of _HomePageState. That is, in your _HomePageState class. _HomePageState() { locSection = .... }